# For Each array-element subscribe to MQTT topic in async await query function

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, mqtt

The following code works fine, if I provide mqttTopics synchronously as array.

The connection is not established nor the "subscribed successfully" logged, if I try to wrap the code (from before declaration of mqttTopics) into an async function, in order to await the promised query response.

Could anyone please explain why it can't be put into a function like that and point me into the right direction regarding waiting for the query in some way?

```js
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
let mqttClient = mqtt.connect('mqtt://127.0.0.1:188:1889');
let { singledbentry, refresh } = require("./database.js")

async function mqttSubscribe() {

let mqttTopics = await refresh('SELECT topicname, topictimetable, topicid FROM mqttsubscriptions');

mqttClient.on('connect', function() {
    mqttTopics.forEach(element => {
        mqttClient.subscribe(element.topicname);        
    });
    
    console.log('subscribed successfully');
});
mqttClient.on('message', function(topic,message) {
    console.log(topic);
    console.log(message.toString());
});

}
module.exports = mqttSubscribe;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the refresh be performed after the connection is made?  That would argue for moving that line into the `on.('connect'` callback.  If `refresh` is async (I don't know what database.js is, but refresh sounds async from its name and SQL-looking param), it should be awaited.

Comment: shouldn't you be showing us the code that *doesn't* work? it's a bit hard to imagine from this.

Comment: async function mqttSubscribe() { let mqttTopics = await refresh....//remaining code//...toString());});   
                                             }

Comment: @danh yes - that allows me to put async into the function of mqttClient.on and run it as desired within the file. Now I just need to see if I can export it as module somehow